# Can't access wp-admin Internal Server Error 500

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, 500-internal-error

I suddenly can't access `company.co.za/wp-admin`, as it redirects to

```
http://company.co.za/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%company.co.za%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

with error 500

What should I do to resolve this?

I know I can try disabling all plugins, but how do I do that without loggin into wp dashboard? Is there some other step I should take?

Thank you

Comment: you have check .htaccess file? and  please connect ftp and rename plugin dir.

Comment: @vikrantzilpe Is there anything specific I need to check in htaccess?  I will try renaming the plugin dir and report back

Comment: ok i will wait your report

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are so many for internal server error. The main reasons for internal server errors are.

1. Corrupt .htaccess file
2. PHP Memory limit
3. Corrupted plugin
4. Incompatible PHP version
5. Corrupted core files

In oder to fix this issue, you need to investigate in step by step order.

To solve this issue first of all you need to enable Debug mode and check the issue. after that try with restoring .htacess file, enabling default theme, disabling plugins etc.

if you still facing 500 internal server issue, check the tutorial on wpera --> https://www.wpera.net/500-internal-server-error/

Answer (score 1):

500 errors are hard to diagnose; they are sort of generic. Sometimes the access logs will give you hints. And they are not consistent - they come and go sometimes.

I'd temporarily rename the plugins folder to disable them, then look at the site. If the problem does not reoccur, then put the plugin folders back one-two at a time to identify.

If possible, also change to one of the 'twenty' themes temporarily. And, check with your hosting support to see if they have ideas that are specific to your site.

Answer (score 1):

Did you just add a plugin or change a theme?  if you cannot access anything, go to phpmyadmin through the cpanel through your hosting provider.

1. Find your wp database.
2. Go to `wp_options` table.
3. If you changed plugins, run the SQL: UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'a:0:{}' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';

-or-

Find Option_name 'active_plugins' and remove the plugin from the code.  Each plugin will start with 0;#;  I typically copy and paste this whole thing into notepad in case it is not the plugin that does it.

[image]

[image]

*** If you changed themes ***
3) Find Option_name 'template' and change the value to the name of the theme you had it before
4) Find Option_name 'Stylesheet' and change the value to the name of theme (typically a theme will have the same name stylesheet)
[image]

hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I've had this a few times and think it was caused by Wordpress auto updates. My fix is to FTP in to the site and rename the `plugins` folder to `plugins.old` or something similar then access the dashboard, check that you're running the latest version of Wordpress, one site told me I was running an old insecure version of PHP(5) and so I upgraded to 7.2 and then renamed the `plugins` folder back to normal and everything works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix ---  download a copy of the latest WordPress (wordpress.org)
Open the downloaded wp zip-file and drag only the includes folder to your desktop.

zip that new includes folder then upload it to replace the old (renamed Includes folder)

Final step - Login and delete the old includes folder.

You may now log in to your admin account.

Comment: That might work, but as the accepted answer says there are many other possible reasons you'd get a 500 error here.

Comment: Please don't invite users to visit your website, *especially* when it's commercial. Remarks of that nature can be considered as spam, and are inappropriate on the Stack Exchange network. Feel free to share a link to your website on your profile page, but don't add it to answers.

Answer (score 0):

[WPBeginner](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/) have a really good troubleshooter on 500, particularly when it comes to enabling the debug logs:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Often happens when `.htaccess` is bad or missing, or something wrong with `wp-config.php`. Case in point with the latter when copying code in from a googled page which had right and left quotes instead of the ANSII single quote.

Syntax errors are picked up in the log for easy analysis.